# How to stop build programatically in Next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

Is there a way to stop `npm run build` programatically in Next.js as soon as a certain Error occurs in `getStaticProps`?
Just throwing an Error does not stop the build process.

Comment: did you try process.exit(1) ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to achieve the same thing but apparently there is no official way. What I've tried is the following code inside `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = async (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  try {
    console.log("fetching app info", phase)
    const appInfo = await fetchAppInfo()
    fs.writeJson("./src/appInfo.json", appInfo)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    throw e
  }

  return yourConfig
}
```

If you don't return the expected config for next js, the build procedure will be cancled